# Why was the then callback for this Promise never called?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have this simple script, let's call it `hello.js`:

```
async function main() {
    console.log("Hello world!");
}

main().then(() => "All done").catch(e => console.err(e));
```

I'm running it with `Node.js` (version `10.15.0`):

```
node hello.js
```

and all I'm receiving for output is

```
Hello world
```

while I expected to have something like

```
Hello world
All done
```

Am I having trouble understanding how promises work or is it  something else?

Comment: You need to display the string somehow. <cough>console.log<cough>

Comment: Should I delete the question or is it worth keeping? Not really used to asking a lot of questions here

Comment: Probably not worth keeping it. Its essentially a typo. Happens to everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the function you are passing to `then`.

```js
const f = () => "All done";

f();
```

It **just** returns a string.

If you want it to be logged somewhere, then you need to log it.

For example:

```js
async function main() {
  console.log("Hello world!");
}

main()
  .then(() => "All done")
  .then(string => console.log(string))
  .catch(e => console.err(e));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing console log there.

```
main().then(() => console.log("All done")).catch(e => console.err(e));
```

Comment: Wow. I really need a rubber duck, I spent an hour on this. Thanks!